# File Transform task for app.config connectionstrings

Tags: azure-pipelines

Im setting up a release pipeline task to transform my app.config using variables to replace several connectionstring values.  These properties are not in the  node, but rather in a seperate  node.  Does the File Transform task work only with settings in the  node or anywhere in the file?  The attribute on the connectionstring properties are name and "connectionString", eg.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="conn1" connectionString="conn 1 string"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

What do I put in the value field of task?
Something like this?
(a) connectionString="conn 1 changed string"
or
(b)  "conn 1 changed string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a Transform file, for example:

[image]

Transform file:
[image]

For details of how translations are processed, see [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic).

To apply XML transformation to configuration files (*.config) you must specify a newline-separated list of transformation file rules using the syntax:

```
-transform <path to the transform file> -xml <path to the source file> -result <path to the result file>
```

For example:
[image]

[image]

For details , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops).

**Update**:

We can also use XML variable substitution part of File transform task. Then define the required values in release pipeline variables to transform the varibale.

**Note** : Variable substitution takes effect only on the `applicationSettings`, `appSettings`, `connectionStrings`, and `configSections` elements of configuration files.

For details , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution).

Comment: Interesting, I had seen mention of doing this but also without.  I managed to get my solution working - no transform file.  The values in the config file get replaced with the variable value using version (b) in the original post above.  I suppose my question was more directed at variable replacements and how that works,

Comment: Aha, yes, we can replace variables through the variable substitution part in the File transform task. For this issue, using Transform file is complicated, but variable substitution only works on some specific elements of the configuration files. I updated this to the answer.

Comment: ok, thats what I think im missing - the transform file. I was under the impression, the variables would replace the value of the corresponding items in the config files on their own.  Will try this and check.