# Can I change a specific attribute value in a XML file in DevOps using XML Variable Substitution?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two environments, Dev and Prod, I am using [XML variable Substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmlvarsubs) to change the values according to the environment.

What I am trying to do is change the value of a specific attribute. For instance, I have the following:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_1" binding="binding_1" bindingConfiguration="configuration_1" contract="contract_1" name="firstLink" />
 <endpoint address="url_2" binding="binding_2" bindingConfiguration="configuration_2" contract="contract_2" name="secondLink" />
</client>
```

and I want to substitute the `address` values to `url_3` and the second endpoint to `url_4`. So, it would look something like this:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_3" binding="binding_3" bindingConfiguration="configuration_3" contract="contract_3" name="thirdLink" />
 <endpoint address="url_4" binding="binding_4" bindingConfiguration="configuration_4" contract="contract_4" name="fourthLink" />
</client>
```

How it is on the DevOps side is that there is a `key, value, environment` pairs where the key is the name.

is there a way to specifically change the `address` using the same convention? Address is what I am trying to change, and I am not allowed install any outside extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, variable substitution only works on some specific elements of the configuration files. If the configuration file you want to substitute does not belong to `applicationSettings`, `appSettings`, `connectionStrings`, and `configSections` elements and you are not allowed to use any outside extensions, then I think you need to use [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation).

You can transform the values in the config file by creating a Transform file. For related syntax, please follow [Web.config Transformation Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)).

We can also use the built-in [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task to transform.

To apply XML transformation to configuration files (*.config) you must specify a newline-separated list of transformation file rules using the syntax:

```
-transform <path to the transform file> -xml <path to the source file> -result <path to the result file>
```

For example:

[image]

For details, you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796643/file-transform-task-for-app-config-connectionstrings/63808477#63808477).

[XML transformation notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation):

By default, MSBuild applies the transformation as it generates the web package if the `<DependentUpon>` element is already present in the transform file in the `*.csproj` file. In such cases, the Azure App Service Deploy task will fail because there is no further transformation applied on the `Web.config` file. Therefore, it is recommended that the `<DependentUpon>` element is removed from all the transform files to disable any build-time configuration when using XML transformation.

Comment: so I added a file transformation task in the release pipeline, and added the following transformation rule `-transform **\*.UAT.config -xml **\Web.config`, and I got a warining that it wasn't able to to apply the file trasnformations `##[warning]Unable to apply transformation for the given package.`? I don't have file transformations checked in my deploy task, I am not sure if that is it or not?

Comment: I also tried `-transform **\*.UAT.config -xml **\*.config`, but that didn't work either

Comment: The issue was with the `<DependsUpon>` tags in the csproj file

Comment: By default, MSBuild applies the transformation as it generates the web package if the `<DependentUpon>` element is already present in the transform file in the `*.csproj` file. In such cases, the Azure App Service Deploy task will fail because there is no further transformation applied on the `Web.config` file. Therefore, it is recommended that the `<DependentUpon>` element is removed from all the transform files to disable any build-time configuration when using XML transformation. I add XML transformation notes to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you see in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution):

> Variable substitution takes effect only on the applicationSettings, appSettings, connectionStrings, and configSections elements of configuration files. If you are looking to substitute values outside of these elements you can use a (parameters.xml) file, however you will need to use a 3rd party pipeline task to handle the variable substitution.

So in your case you can use [token replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

You just need to put tokens in your file like this:

```xml
<client>
 <endpoint address="#{URL_1}#" binding="binding_1" bindingConfiguration="configuration_1" contract="contract_1" name="firstLink" />
 <endpoint address="#{URL_1}#" binding="binding_2" bindingConfiguration="configuration_2" contract="contract_2" name="secondLink" />
</client>
```

Where `URL_1` and `URL_2` are variables defined in the pipeline.